# How to rewrite a SELECT ... CROSS JOIN LATERAL ... statement for older PostgreSQL versions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, lateral

I am faced with a query similar to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM invoicable_interval i,
  LATERAL partition_into_months(i.start_date, i.stop_or_current_date) p;
```

... where partition_into_months is defined similar to this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION partition_into_months(start_date DATE, stop_date DATE)
  RETURNS TABLE (start_date DATE, stop_date DATE, days INT)
AS $$ ... $$
LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;
```

So I am doing a cross join with a variable interval for the secondary table, hence the (redundant) keyword LATERAL.

This works fine with PostgreSQL 9.3.6 and 9.4.2, however, with 9.1.3 I get the following error message:

```
[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
  Position: 398
```

The indicated position is the dot in the expression "i.start_date".

How can I rewrite this SQL query in order to port it back to PostgreSQL 9.1.3 ?

Comment: Looks to me that the function can be replaced by a (aggregating) view, and/or a generate_series(). Depends on the body of the function, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL supports calling set-returning functions in the `SELECT` clause. This is somewhat deprecated now that we have `LATERAL` and is certainly discouraged because it has rather erratic behaviour, but it remains useful.

In your case you could write:

```
SELECT 
  i.*,
  (partition_into_months(i.start_date, i.stop_or_current_date)).*
FROM invoicable_interval i;
```

However, this may result in one call to `partition_into_months` per column returned because `(fn).*` is basically macro-expanded into `(fn).col1, (fn).col2, ...`. To avoid this, you can wrap it in a subquery, e.g.

```
SELECT (x.i).*, (x.p).*
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    i,
    partition_into_months(i.start_date, i.stop_or_current_date) p
  FROM invoicable_interval i
) x(i,p);
```

Note that weird results will be encountered in the presence of multiple set returning functions in the `SELECT` list. It isn't a cross-join like you would expect. For example, compare:

```
SELECT generate_series(1,4), generate_series(1,4)
```

to

```
SELECT generate_series(1,4), generate_series(1,3);
```

Comment: The second example looks interesting, but I get '[42P01] ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "i"
  Position: 8'

Comment: Found a fix: You need to write "SELECT (x.i).*, (x.p).* FROM ...". Would you mind updating your solution? Then I will pick it.